# Strongly typed worker

Tags: typescript

I'm playing around with some logic to create a strongly typed worker, which should be able to accept only a pre-defined set of messages, and respond with the appropriate response type given the message.

Something like the following

```js
type MsgStruct<T, P, R> = {
  type: T
  payload: P
  response: R
}

type FooMsg = MsgStruct<'foo', number, number>
type BarMsg = MsgStruct<'bar', boolean, string>
type BazMsg = MsgStruct<'baz', string, boolean[]>

// Messages that can be handled by the worker
type WorkerMsg =
  | FooMsg
  | BarMsg
  | BazMsg

// Creation logic
type StronglyTypedWorker<T> = T extends { type: infer A, payload: infer B, response: infer C } ? {
  postMessage: (msg: { type: A, payload: B }) => Promise<C>
} : never

declare const worker: Worker
declare const createWorker: <T extends MsgStruct<unknown, unknown, unknown>>(worker: Worker) => StronglyTypedWorker<T>

// Example
const strongWorker = createWorker<WorkerMsg>(worker)

declare const foo: FooMsg

const fooRes = strongWorker.postMessage(foo)
  .then(res => {}) // expecting `res` to be of type `number` here
```

This doesn't work, as `tsc` complains with

> Argument of type 'FooMsg' is not assignable to parameter of type 'never'.
> The intersection '{ type: "foo"; payload: number; } & { type: "bar"; payload: boolean; } & { type: "baz"; payload: string; }' was reduced to 'never' because property 'type' has conflicting types in some constituents.ts(2345)

Is there a better way to do this? Or rather, one that works?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You were almost there.

The problem was in `createWorker` return type, it was a union of functions.

When you want to call union of functions, their arguments will intersect/merge. Because function arguments are in contravariant positions.
Thet's why you got `never` type.

You can read more about it in my [article](https://catchts.com/react-props)

All you need to do is to produce function overloading, in other words you should derive intersection of functions instead of union:

```js
type MsgStruct<T, P, R> = {
    type: T
    payload: P
    response: R
}

type FooMsg = MsgStruct<'foo', number, number>
type BarMsg = MsgStruct<'bar', boolean, string>
type BazMsg = MsgStruct<'baz', string, boolean[]>

// Messages that can be handled by the worker
type WorkerMsg =
    | FooMsg
    | BarMsg
    | BazMsg

// Creation logic
type StronglyTypedWorker<T> = T extends { type: infer A, payload: infer B, response: infer C } ? {
    postMessage: (msg: { type: A, payload: B }) => Promise<C>
} : never

declare const worker: Worker

// credits goes to https://stackoverflow.com/a/50375286
type UnionToIntersection<U> = (U extends any ? (k: U) => void : never) extends (
    k: infer I
) => void
    ? I
    : never;

declare const createWorker: <T extends MsgStruct<unknown, unknown,unknown>>(worker: Worker) => UnionToIntersection<StronglyTypedWorker<T>>

// Example
const strongWorker = createWorker<WorkerMsg>(worker)

declare const foo: FooMsg

const fooRes = strongWorker.postMessage(foo)
    .then(res => { }) // res is number
```

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ssl=39&ssc=22&pln=1&pc=1#code/C4TwDgpgBAsgzgcwMrAE4FcDGwA8AVAGigAUiAlAPigF4oBvAKCmalEgC4o8mWwBDEABsA9nwAmnYj2aoIcMMIB2cCJzIMAvgwZtoAMWHD4CGrEQoM2HAHIAZoetFF6ALYAjCKieuPqCjvBoACE%20VGNTYwssXGs3UMcoN0NBCD5FIjg0AEtFBH9dKBCAL3DaSLRomziihMzUHIQiJOEUtIBtAF1-BgB6Htg5OD4EOVYACz5gKEw0xOgJxTEUsUSQcegAd2FUAGtPAMgoAHVtvbDEGmkoAB8oAyNEK9uQ84Qnwr4Sx97%20gGFZSZZJRQEQILKYA7QCxKBCCEB4QJiE67Tz4Ki0PBQCAAD2AEEWcHorECnBytk8UAAgkR%20EJRBIoGSKUEiLJ5EoVKTFOTUFBflANFAAPz0K4KTIwQbDVRQAAULkQnDoxI4VJpAhE4k4QQFAEoaFRiKhhC4siocL9-ILOIoIAA3fYMMQQTCCULQTAcqZbFGoTjIs7aPrTWRiLLAQkIYSjYDCKBjYDAMBwdh9TJ8TA7YQO1C2EQbAB0npcPT4PQArAAGADMAHZywAmAAcADZIVAAKqKIGKPDCACSijxqBU2B7OA76LlHaxuPxYkJaTWItlO04Hf11CoduEWRWNvtnn1OLxBLlVzXjO5FP7DE3293YiuItvLCgB5zAG5tM7Xe7pl6IapHiAaeJw%20CzqeC5mMgFRWOgig7IowgbOkUAIUhKHpBhyGoRQFCyj6Zz%20qcR4Gp23ZKH2g7DqOwDjtCuRwgikBIqRqBot0wYAKLYnwLhgCkDCesoUx1DCoG8rQmAAiB7E4JJxgEURR4-i6bqyABolQPYwicPcxjaCJmQ6YYZCjLQ4m5JJBbisAkpwEMIyyrpupXAWwBjPispsuRyoaLqQA)

Btw, most of the time you don't need a union of functions